# Can't access collection admin page after detach / reattach-TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

I have 2 instances of TFS which are A & B
A consists of 3 collections and B consists of 1 collection.

I recently moved 1 collection from B ===> A instance.

After that I am getting the following error while accessing the admin page.

```
VS402375: Can't find the process associated with team project '76916fec-d89d-43cd-a2f6-89cf83d8100f'. Contact support to resolve this error.
```

When i checked the Project ID & Values for 3 collections, They look same but for the fourth collection(which was moved from B==>A) which is different.

If I go ahead and update the values(process template id) for the project_id's, The issue will be resolved or not?

can you let me know.

PFA https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/a31160d4-0bca-4d94-8444-6cd0f4f01da4/cant-access-collection-admin-page-after-detach-reattach?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: How did you move it? Did you detach the collection first, then reattach it?

Comment: Yes Daniel! I have followed couple of steps.1) Detach the collection from B 2)Backed up the collection database 3)Move the collection database 4)Attached the collection from A instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure that you exactly follow the instructions on [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection).

Base on the thread you mentioned and your description, the problem should be that the default process templates in `tfs_configuration` of the new install had IDs that didn't match the projects in the new collection.

So, you can try to backup the DBs first.

Then try to update the corresponding `CurrentProcessTemplateId` for the moved team project to match the ID retrieved from `tfs_configuration`, that means update the table: `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties]`. As update the `tfs_configuration` may cause problems for other three collections.

e.g.:

```
update [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties]  set value = 'the template ID retrieved from A' where Name = 'CurrentProcessTemplateId' and project_id = 'your team project id'
```

If that still not work, just try to also update the `OriginalProcessTemplateId`

```
update [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties]  set value = 'the template ID retrieved from A' where Name = 'OriginalProcessTemplateId' and project_id = 'your team project id'
```

Comment: Thank you Andy!! I will implement the steps as you suggested and update you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy! It worked out. The admin page is working fine after I made the changes as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties] where name = 'CurrentProcessTemplateId' and project_id=''
delete from table [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties] where name = 'OriginalProcessTemplateId' and project_id=''
delete from table [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_project_properties] where name = 'ProcessTemplateType' and project_id=''
```

Running above commands helped me.